# Loss doesn't get below ~60 and test accuracy never gets above ~40% using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

**The problem**

Using a DNNClassifier on Tensorflow and can never get my loss below around 60 and test accuracy above about a 40%. I was having a problem before, where my test accuracy was almost dead set at 25%, but after normalizing all my inputs, I was able to bring my test accuracy up a bit, but not much.

**The data**

All you need to know about the data is I have about 127,000 records of crime rate data. 15 features and one label. The purpose of the network is to classify them into the correct population quartile (which is based on the population of each county) So the output label is solely 4 classes (0-3).

**The code**

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import os

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
csv_path = dir_path + "/testing.csv"
CSV_COLUMN_NAMES = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', 'Quartile']


def load_data():

    all = pd.read_csv(csv_path, names=CSV_COLUMN_NAMES, header=0).sample(frac=1)

    x = all.drop(['Quartile'], axis=1)
    y = all[['Quartile']].copy()

    size = x.shape[0]
    cutoff = int(0.75*size)

    train_x = x.head(cutoff)
    train_y = y.head(cutoff)

    test_x = x.tail(size-cutoff)
    test_y = y.tail(size-cutoff)

    return (train_x, train_y), (test_x, test_y)


def train_input_fn(features, labels, batch_size):

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(features), labels))

    dataset = dataset.shuffle(1000).repeat().batch(batch_size)

    return dataset


def eval_input_fn(features, labels, batch_size):

    features=dict(features)

    if labels is None:
        inputs = features
    else:
        inputs = (features, labels)

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(inputs)

    assert batch_size is not None, "batch_size must not be None"
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)

    return dataset


def main(argv):

    batch_size = 50

    (train_x, train_y), (test_x, test_y) = load_data()

    my_feature_columns = []
    for key in train_x.keys():
        my_feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key=key))

    classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
        feature_columns=my_feature_columns,
        hidden_units=[10, 10],
        optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001),
        n_classes=4)

    # training
    classifier.train(
        input_fn=lambda:train_input_fn(train_x, train_y, batch_size), steps=5000)

    # testing
    eval_result = classifier.evaluate(
        input_fn=lambda:eval_input_fn(test_x, test_y, batch_size))

    print('\nTest set accuracy: {accuracy:0.3f}\n'.format(**eval_result))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
    tf.app.run(main)
```

**What I've tried**

- Messing with my learning rate in the gradient descent optimizer
- Changing the loss reduction to `MEAN` instead of `SUM` which it defaults to
- Changing my step size (up to 100000 even!)
- Trying only one hidden layer (of size: 10) and two hidden layers (of size: 90 each)

I was hoping that you guys would be able to suggest any possible reasons why my neural network seems to be stalling out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look to the following directions:

- Decrease the number of hidden units the deeper you get in your network (e.g. 10 - 5 but not 10 - 10).
- Use Adam instead of (Stochastic) Gradient Descent, or try another optimization method of the first order.
- Increase the batch size to a power of `2` (64, 128, 256, ...).

Comment: Tried increasing batch size to 64, used 10 - 5 for hidden layers, and tried out the adam optimizer and still getting around the same test accuracy (~40%). I have literally no idea what could be causing this.